# SQL sum across rows

Tags: sql, sum, pivot, window-functions, presto

I'm trying to make a query to obtain this result (Presto sql in case it's relevant)

```
| State  | Region   | City     | Sales-City | Sales-Region | Sales-State |
|--------|----------|----------|------------|--------------|-------------|
| Italy  | Lombardy | Milan    | 100        | 150          | 250         |
| Italy  | Lombardy | Como     | 50         | 150          | 250         |
| Italy  | Tuscany  | Florence | 75         | 100          | 250         |
| Italy  | Tuscany  | Prato    | 25         | 100          | 250         |
| France | Ile de F.| Paris    | 5          | 10           | 20          |
| ..     | ..       | ..       | ..         | ..           | ..          |
```

After writing the basics

```
SELECT State, Region, City,
       SUM(Sales) as "Sales-City"
FROM db
GROUP BY State, Region, City
```

But of course I'm stuck on the Sales-Region / Sales-State parts. What's the way to solve it in terms of performance? It seems ridiculous to have to write two (potentially more) separate WITH statements.

Answer (score 3):

Use window functions!

```
select state, region, city,
       sum(sales) as sales_city,
       sum(sum(sales)) over(partiton by state, region) sales_region,
       sum(sum(sales)) over(partiton by state) sales_state
from db
group by state, region, city
```

Answer (score 2):

Another way to solve this kind of problem would be to use grouping sets or rollup with the relevant combinations for aggregation -

```
SELECT State, Region, City,
       SUM(Sales)
FROM db
GROUP BY GROUPING SETS (
(State),
(State,Region),
(State,Region,City));
```

Or

```
SELECT State, Region, City,
       SUM(Sales)
FROM db
GROUP BY ROLLUP (State, Region, City);
```